# Get notification when customer updates account

Tags: magento-2.1, module, customer, email, notification

Is it possible to get an email notification to the admin of a magento 2 store whenever a customer changes his account details like address or something?

Is there some kind of hook I can make a module for?

Comment: whenever customer edit the account you can get it by the event customer_account_edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can play around using the following events:

for customer's account changes the event

```
customer_account_edited
```

for customer's address changes the event

```
customer_address_save_after or customer_address_save_before
```